# How to create Texture2D with CreateExternalTexture and a pointer passed from C++ library?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, textures, directx-11

I am trying to understand how to establish communication between C++ DirectX11 code and Unity Engine.

What I am trying to do is create a very simple `ID3D11Texture2D` in C++ and then pass it to Unity, creating its `Texture2D` by the means of CreateExternalTexture method.

So, I have a C++ DLL VS Project where I have this one function:

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* GetTexture()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("GetTexture.log");

    const int width = 640;
    const int height = 480;

    unsigned char* pixels = new unsigned char[width * height * 4];
    unsigned char* pixelsP = pixels;


    int numPixels = (int)(width * height);

    ID3D11Texture2D* tex = nullptr;
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* shaderView = nullptr;

    ID3D11Device* device = CreateDX11device();

    if (!device)
    {
        myfile << "Cannot create DX11 device" << endl;
        myfile.close();
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        myfile << "Successfully created DX11 device" << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++)
    {
        *(pixelsP) = 255;
        *(pixelsP + 1) = 0;
        *(pixelsP + 2) = 0;
        *(pixelsP + 3) = 122;
        pixelsP += 4;
    }

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData = { 0 };
    initData.pSysMem = (const void*)pixels;
    initData.SysMemPitch = width * 4;
    initData.SysMemSlicePitch = width * height * 4;

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc = {};
    desc.Width = width;
    desc.Height = height;
    desc.MipLevels = 1;
    desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;//D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;// | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;//D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;

    HRESULT hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, &initData, &tex);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        myfile << "FAILED TO CREATE DX TEXTURE" << endl;
        myfile << hr << endl;
        myfile.close();
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        myfile << "Successfully Created DX Texture" << endl;
    }

    myfile.close();

    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&shaderResourceViewDesc, sizeof(shaderResourceViewDesc));
    
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

    device->CreateShaderResourceView(tex, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &shaderView);

    return shaderView;
}
```

And here is how I create my DX11 device:

```
ID3D11Device* CreateDX11device()
{
    ID3D11Device* device = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    UINT createDeviceFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] = {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    };

    UINT numDriverTypes = ARRAYSIZE(driverTypes);

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] = {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
    };

    ID3D11DeviceContext* context = nullptr;

    UINT numFeatureLevels = ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels);
    
    hr = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        nullptr,
        createDeviceFlags,
        featureLevels,
        numFeatureLevels,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &device,
        nullptr,
        &context);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        cout << "Could not create DX11 device" << endl;
        return nullptr;
    }

    cout << "DX Device Created" << endl;

    return device;
}
```

Now, the function `GetTexture` is simply called from C# code in Unity and the result is treated as `IntPtr`. I then start creating the Texture2D and setting the texture to view the result in Unity:

```
[DllImport("TestDX11.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern IntPtr GetTexture();

void Start()
{
    IntPtr ptr = GetTexture();

    Texture2D texture = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(640, 480, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false, ptr);
    GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = texture;
}
```

The problem is that I am expecting to see a red image in Unity app but I see nothing, the texture is blank, as if I was not putting anything in it. And to be sure I tried outputting the received pointer from the DLL and it is non-null, so I do actually get a pointer at the Texture. I feel quite lost at this point as I tried playing around with different flags during texture creation, but nothing really helped.

I also tried to send `ID3D11Texture2D*` instead of `ID3D11ResourceShaderView*` as [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture.html) points out, but it crashes Unity when `CreateExternalTexture` method is called for some reason.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Seems you are creating your texture using your own device, you need to use the one provided by unity under the hood (as textures created by different devices are not "shareable"

Comment: @catflier thanks! That's an interesting suggestion. How would I get the device used by Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you are creating a Texture using a device created by D3D11CreateDevice.

This is a different device than the one used by Unity, so when you call Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture, either Unity or The device used by Unity will detect it doesn't own this resource, so it can't use it.

In order to have this texture accessible by Unity, you need to create the texture with the device used by Unity itself.

To do this, you need to use Unity's Low-level [native plug-in interface](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html)

You need to declare a few specific functions in your dll so Unity can detect them and then call.

In your case, you can use UnityPluginLoad "callback, and retrieve the device from there (for simplicity, the below code does not handle cases as per Unity using Direct3D12 or another graphics API).

```
extern "C" void UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API 
UnityPluginLoad(IUnityInterfaces* interfaces)
{
    ID3D11Device* dxDevice;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* dxDeviceContext;
    dxDevice = interfaces->Get<IUnityGraphicsD3D11>()->GetDevice();
    dxDevice ->GetImmediateContext(&dxDeviceContext);
}
```

Any texture created with this device will be accessible from Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture

Note : Since Unity Direct3D11 device (at the time I did some project in Unity, which was some years ago, I'm not sure about latest versions) , was using D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_FLAG::D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED), you need to create your textures in the standard Unity thread, otherwise you might (will) have potential crashes (in our case we had to start unity and our app with a custom commandline to disable this flag).

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you for help!